# ExtJS 4 CheckboxModel and grid columns defaults

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid with `selType: 'checkboxmodel'` and defaults config for its columns, i.e. `hidden: true`, thus my checkbox column is hidden aswell. Ofcourse I can move defaults properties to columns items and all work just fine but is there way to setup `hidden: false` for checkbox column?

[Simple fiddle to illustrate issue](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13pf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `getHeaderConfig` method of `CheckboxModel` and add `hidden: false`:

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13rk